# How to show the progress bar onViewCreated in Fragment?

Tags: android, tensorflow, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, textureview

I'm a very new in android. It is currently making apps using TensorFlower on Android. I use textureview in Fragment, and the screen shows a white screen while the learning file of tensorflow  loads. The time is about five seconds. I want to show the progress bar during  loading the time. I want you to tell me. Thank you.

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Thank you for your interest.

My code referred to the flagging data code below. You may refer to the Fragment section of this code.

https://github.com/sauvignon1989/PoseEstimationForMobileInJava/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/butcher2/Camera2BasicFragment.java

Comment: Hi, it's better if you post your code in the actual issue, it will increase the number of people looking at it.

Comment: I solved the problem myself. Next time I have another problem, I will follow the advice. appreciate one's interest!